# Will removing a HTML section block from my all website pages, affects SEO and my website rank?

Tags: html, performance, optimization, seo

So I have a hidden HTML section block that is heavy and requires multiple HTTP requests, which slowing my website page speed load.

So I am trying to implement a **lazyloading** methodology for this specific section to only render after someone clicking on the [SHOW] button.
I want to know if removing this entire HTML section from my web pages will cause a problem for Google or any other bots and will damage my rank? or not?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Improving the overall performance of your site is always a good idea. In fact, page speed directly affects your ranking, so best improve it by all means:

- https://moz.com/learn/seo/page-speed
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/search-ads-speed

Hidden text, on the other hand, might hurt your ranking, at least if done the wrong way:

- https://www.searchenginejournal.com/hidden-text-seo/208866/

Since in your case, the hidden parts seem to hugely impair your page loading, lazy-loading them would be the way to go.